# Jmeter scheduler repeating values from csv data config

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am doing **performance testing of add-to-cart functionality** of an e-commerce website and the scheduler I have kept for **15 mins**.

I am using **20 users** **50s ramp-up** time and adding **5 products** for every user

The add-to-cart functionality I have kept inside a loop controller and the loop count is **5**

Now the problem is that it is adding **more than 5 products** for a particular user
and also repeating some products

I want to add unique **5 products** for a particular user.
I am reading products from **csv data config**

[Screenshot is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhtNz.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is practically impossible to suggest a good configuration without seeing a partial CSV file with products contents and the way you configured the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), most probably you need to set [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy) to `All Threads` so each virtual user would read the new line on each iteration.

An easier way would be just switching to [__StringFromFile](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function which basically returns the next line from the given file each time it's being called.

A harder, but the most robust way would be going for [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) - it has `UNIQUE` parameter which guarantees the returned value would be unique even when you run your JMeter test in [Distributed Mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).